# Alt key codes for dashes giving wrong characters in Windows

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, keyboard-layout, alt-code

If I type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, I get `☼`, rather than `–` (en dash).

If I type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, I get `ù`, rather than `—` (em dash).

I would have expected to get dashes in both cases. I'm pretty sure it used to work.

This is happening in Word 2007 and Office 2007 on Windows 7.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You previously got an *em dash* or *en dash* because 150 and 151 are their code points in [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which is the default [Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_code_pages) (A.K.A ANSI code page) for US computers. ANSI code page is what you get when typing Alt code with a zero prefix, and if you don't put a zero prefix then the [OEM code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#MS-DOS_code_pages) will be used, which is [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) by default for US computers

You somehow changed the code page from Windows 1252 to another one. So if you want to get it back then the simplest way is to run `chcp 1252` in cmd

But Alt codes shouldn't be relied upon right from the beginning, because their results depend on code page **and** application. Many applications will treat those codes differently on their own, for example MS Office as you can see. In MS Office just type the Unicode code point and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> instead. So just type <kbd>2013</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>2014</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for en dash and em dash respectively

But to get em/en dashes you should use the built-in AutoCorrect feature of Office instead. Type `-` or `--` normally and it'll automatically change to the correct dash in the current context. You can add your own custom replacement characters in the other AutoCorrect tabs

[image: AutoFormat MS Word options]

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert Unicode characters using their Unicode ID (2013 for the dash you're using) by typing it out and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> with the insertion pointer directly after the number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct font. If you change your font to 'Lucinda Console' it will fix this. Or you could find the right dash in the font you *are* using.

Comment: No, it does the same thing with Lucida Console. I've found out that the problem has to do with code pages. It seems I am using code page 850, which is not the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> to insert a dash character. This will work reguardless of the font selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Word `Insert Symbol` dialog to insert the symbol into your document.

**Find a Unicode character code**

When you select a Unicode character in the Symbol dialog box, its character code appears in the Character code box.

1. On the Insert tab, in the Symbols group, click Symbol, and then click More Symbols.
2. On the Symbols tab, in the Font box, click the font that you want.
3. In the from box, click Unicode (hex).
4. The Unicode character code is displayed in the Character code box.

[ [Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-symbol-or-special-character-81e64967-74c0-4fd9-814a-3aa867d4cfce) ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Character map to insert a character into Word.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `charmap`, and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Click the character that you'd like.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
5. Open your document and paste the character where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but a combination of choosing the appropriate keyboard from 'Edit language and keyboard options' and ensuring the 'Num Lock' was on got me back into — instead of ù.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).